# List files in folder with Google Drive v3

Tags: java, rest, google-drive-api

I want to list all files in a Google drive Folder with Google drive api v3. I have the Folder id already so i Need to get the Folder by id and then list its files. (and get file Information further on later) The Problem is the api doc just Shows api calls for files but not for Folders. See https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference

Can't that be done in v3 anymore? v2 offers such calls if i remember correctly but i suppose i shouldn't use v2 anymore because it will be deprecated in near future, won't it?

EDIT: The Folder is public by the way

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files , particularly "Files with ID within a collection, e.g. parents collection '1234567' in parents"

Answer (score 2):

To build on what Raserhin said, to list for a specific folder id:

```
q='folderid' in parents
q='1eWTOT0KUZiDko-A0JsLCqbhTJ3oOMJ6Wb' in parents
```

The full HTTP request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%22folderid%22%20in%20parents&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see it's here to lists or searches files:
GET  /files

Comment: i can't do that for a specific Folder Id as far as i can see in the docs. i can't find any Input Parameter for "Folder id"

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve what you are trying to do with the [`list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) files request, just make sure that the files you are retrieving have the right parent ("folder) using the right [`Query Strings`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files).

For example If you wanted to retrieve all the file under the root folder you could query something like so:

`q=root in parents`

Or if you want the full HTTP request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%22root%22%20in%20parents&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

If you want to check for only the folders in your drive you can also do it by the same request but filtering with the [`specific MIME type`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#search_for_specific_files_or_folders_on_the_current_users_my_drive).