# How to list the contents of a Google Drive folder by ID with the V3 API Python client?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

The official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) is not helping much on this topic. First of all it is an example on searching by mimeType, not by parent ID. And then I replaced the search term by the example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137661/list-files-in-folder-with-google-drive-v3) and it still does not find anything. My code is below. Note that the function is named `copy_folder` just because I was actually trying to copy all files and sub-folders in a folder to a new folder and the first step is to get the contents of the source folder. And the source folder is in a team drive. The 'files' key in the response is just empty while in the folder I tested there are actually files and sub-folders.

```
def copy_folder(service, src, dst):
    """
    Copies a folder. It will create a new folder in dst with the same name as src,
    and copies the contents of src into the new folder
    src: Source folder's id
    dst: Destination folder's id that the source folder is going to be copied to
    """
    page_token = None
    while True:
        response = service.files().list(q="'%s' in parents" % src,
                                        supportsAllDrives=True,
                                        spaces='drive',
                                        fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                        pageToken=page_token,
                                        ).execute()
        for file in response.get('files', []):
            # Process change
            print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, I think that in order to retrieve the files in the subfolders, it is required to use the recursive function. For this, I have created the library for achieving it. So in this answer, I would like to achieve your goal using a library of [getfilelistpy](https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy). When this library is used, the script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please install [getfilelistpy](https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy) as follows.

```
$ pip install getfilelistpy
```

And, after you copied and pasted the following script, please set the variable of `src`.

```
import pickle
import os.path
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from getfilelistpy import getfilelist

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'

creds = None

creFile = 'token_sample.pickle'
if os.path.exists(creFile):
    with open(creFile, 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'client_secret.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server()
    with open(creFile, 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

src = '###'  # Please set the folder ID.
fields = 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
resource = {
    "oauth2": creds,
    "id": src,
    "fields": fields,
}
res = getfilelist.GetFileList(resource)
print(dict(res))
```

- In this case, you can also use the scopes of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.

#### Note:

- When you want to retrieve the file list just under the specific folder, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    src = '###'  # Please set the folder ID.
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    fields = 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
    q = "'%s' in parents" % src
    values = []
    nextPageToken = ""
    while True:
        res = service.files().list(q=q, fields=fields, pageSize=1000, pageToken=nextPageToken or "", includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
        values.extend(res.get("files"))
        nextPageToken = res.get("nextPageToken")
        if nextPageToken is None:
            break
    print(values)
  ```
- In this case, in order to retrieve the file list from the shared Drive, please use `supportsAllDrives=True` and `includeItemsFromAllDrives=True`.
- If you cannot retrieve the files, please also add `corpora="drive", driveId="###driveId###"`.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [getfilelistpy](https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy)

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day. The key is to include this parameter: includeItemsFromAllDrives=True

I have not tried your library yet but will definitely take a look.

Comment: @fhcat Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.